# SQL Server Express error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-express

We have a problem with our SQL Express server and need help please. We use this SQL Express server with a banking program on one windows computer. When we try to do some task in the application which was always working fine before we are now getting a error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Google is showing me that we should add entries in `web.config` file to fix this problem. It is explained here:

http://sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-server-reporting-services-error-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/ar-SA/c9d4431a-0d71-4782-8f38-4fb4d5b7a829/ssrs-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object?forum=sqlreportingservices

The problem is that it seems the `web.config` file does not exist in SQL Server Express and I'm not able to fix this issue.

Where can we apply this settings on a SQL Express Server? Does a express server have this `web.config` file?

Comment: What makes you think the error is SQL Server rather than your application?. More details are required to be able to provide assistance. A stack trace, a windows event lot, something because otherwise you are just guessing since that is a generic error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message, including the stack trace. Although that message is commonly associated with hashtables in ASP.NET it can also happen with other things such as certificate issues (Exchange, Delegated/Federated Authentication), .NET Tasks that cannot be continued, etc..